# Web Speech API "making up" whole word out of single letter ("p"->"police" in German)

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

```
var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("kohp");
utterThis.lang = 'de-DE';
speechSynthesis.speak(utterThis);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bawzr0f4/

Why does this code produce the spoken word "kohpolizei" instead of "kohp"?

"Polizei" is the German word for "police", btw.

Edit after some experimentation in the comments section:

```
"kohw" --> "kohweiß",
"kohg" --> "kohgesetz",
"kohb" --> "kohblei"
```

(the suffixes are all German words)

and other prefixes like "leh" also work ("lehp" --> "lehpolizei")

Browsers/System: Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (64-bit) and Firefox 62.0 (64-Bit), Windows 10 Professional

Comment: It says "kohp" when I try it.

Comment: What browser/system?

Comment: Also, "cop" → "Polizei", clearly correct. 

Comment: Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (64-bit) and also on Firefox 62.0 (64-Bit). Windows 10 Professional

Comment: Working on a Mac, Firefox 62.0

Comment: So Windows' speech synthesis system is… weird. ‍♂️

Comment: Dit it maybe cached the previous speech ?

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit No, I don't think so.

Comment: on windows 10 it says kohpolizei on edge, firefox and chrome. funny...

Comment: kohw becomes coweiß. seems to be several characters.

Comment: "lehp" and "lehw" become "lehpolizei" and "lehweiß"

Comment: "kohb" -> "kohblei"

Comment: seems to be a combination of consonant, vocal, (stummes) h and a final consonant? not always though...

Comment: "kohg" -> "kohgesetz" ... wtf

Comment: i guess you just hit a bug

Comment: Any way to report it?

Comment: I think this is specific to Windows 10. It works correctly on Windows 7 and Ubuntu